# How to get a Turkish e-Visa without Schengen permit?

Tags: schengen, turkey

I am from Pakistan, I want to know about eVisa. I don't have a Schengen Permit. How do I get an eVisa for turkey?

Answer (score 6):

[The visa requirements are detailed here](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa). The reason the e-Visa website asks about a Schengen, US, or UK visa or residence permit is that it's not possible for you to get an e-Visa without one.

Instead, you are supposed to apply for a regular visa. As far as I can tell, it's not necessarily more expensive but it means you have to go through a slower process and provide more information in advance.